# QT pro file environment variable lib path

Tags: qt, variables, environment, .profile

Something I'm not getting. I want to include 3 libs in my .pro file. Created an environment variable, and then I add them to the LIBS path. This is OK for 2 times, the third time fails.
In detail:

Environment variable:

> > NETSNMP_DIR C:/usr/net-snmp-5.6.2/win32/lib/debug

.pro file:

```
win32:LIBS += -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR))/netsnmp -lnetsnmpagent -lnetsnmpmibs \
...
```

The above fails ! If I do this however:

```
win32:LIBS += -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)) -lnetsnmp -lnetsnmpagent -LC:/usr/net-snmp-5.6.2/win32/lib/debug -lnetsnmpmibs \
```

it builds fine. If I separate all 3 of them, same result:
This fails:

```
win32:LIBS += -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)) -lnetsnmp \
                -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)) -lnetsnmpagent \
                -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)) -lnetsnmpmibs \
```

This builds just fine:

```
win32:LIBS += -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)) -lnetsnmp \
                -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)) -lnetsnmpagent \
                -LC:/usr/net-snmp-5.6.2/win32/lib/debug -lnetsnmpmibs \
```

Toolchain: `QT 4.8.5`, `QTCreator 2.8.1`, `OS Windows 7`
What am I missing ?
Thanks a lot in advance !

This thing is driving me nuts. I recently came across this post again, and out of the blue I tried this:

```
win32:LIBS +=   -L($$(WINDDK_LIB_WIN7_32B_DIR)) -lws2_32 \
                -L($$(WINDDK_LIB_WIN7_32B_DIR)) -ladvapi32 \
                -L($$(WINDDK_LIB_WIN7_32B_DIR)) -luser32 \
                -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)/lib/debug) -lnetsnmp \
                -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)/lib/debug) -lnetsnmpagent \
                -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)/lib/debug) -lnetsnmpmibs \
                ...
```

Including some libs using an environment variable, simple. Guess what: for some silly odd reason, the WINDDK import works like a charm. The NET_SNMP doesn't. If anybody out there has even the faintest idea, anything that can bring clarity in this matter, would be highly appreciated !

Comment: Seems like code snippets are a bit messed up, and there's a typo in the first line. This is the first code snippet (win32:LIBS += -L($$(NETSNMP_DIR)) -lnetsnmp -lnetsnmpagent -lnetsnmpmibs) and it fails and I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: Where are these netsnmp libraries location? Also, what does it mean that they do not work? What exactly is the error message?

Comment: The net-snmp libs are located in the default install directory: C:/usr/net-snmp-5.6.2/win32/lib/debug. I use an environment variable NETSNMP_DIR C:/usr/net-snmp-5.6.2/win32/lib/debug. Exactly the same way I did for the WINDDK_LIB_WIN7_32B_DIR C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\lib\win7\i386 to include the -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -luser32 libs.
Result is linker says : error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'netsnmp.lib'. Changing the order of the libs, doesn't matter. Error stays.